# How to create an Equity Curve using the "Start Date and "End Date" using Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, charts, google-sheets-formula, sparklines

In the sheet  given below you will see the "Start Date" and "End Date" both as drop drop list. My idea is when i change  both the dates it has to give me a Equity Curve which will be a line graph as per the data mentioned in the drop down list. Say for eg if i mention the start date: 1 Apr,20 & end date:28 Apr,20  it has to take all the Equity Curve data ie starting from 50,000 to 46330.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TUcsv_fs5DDFZ7gotY2WdM1IcoO3gR8G8wXedYVLffk/edit#gid=0

[Sample file]

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
=SPARKLINE(INDIRECT("H"&MATCH(B2, C:C, 0)&":H"&MATCH(B3, C:C, 0)), {"charttype", "line"})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: sheet you shared has been deleted